# How do I undo what I'm currently writing before close()?

Tags: python, file, exception, try-except

```
for i in range(0,5):
    
    f = open("StudentRecords.txt", "a")
    try:
        f.write(input("Name: ")+"\n")
        f.write(str(int(input("ID: ")))+"\n")
        f.write(str(float(input("GPA: ")))+"\n")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: You entered a String for ID or GPA.")
    
    f.close()
```

Here for example if I tried to write a string for GPA, I will catch the error and the program will move on, but the Name and ID of the same iteration will still be written
I want it to only write if all the 3 data are valid.

Comment: you need to figure out if they're valid before trying to write them, use variables and write the variables

Comment: Separate your steps: handle the inputs and save them to variables. Then write that data to the file.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You want to do one thing (only write valid information to your file) but ask about something else (how to un-write data you've already written). That is technically possible actually (you can truncate the file just before the invalid data) but it's more work than just not writing the invalid data in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments said, the best approach is to validate all the data before writing anything. But if you really need to undo, you can do it by saving the file position before each record, seeking back to it, and truncating to remove everything written after.

And rather than reopening the file for each record, you should open it once before the loop. Use `with` to close it automatically when the block is finished.

```
with open("StudentRecords.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(0,5):
        try:
            filepos = f.tell()
            f.write(input("Name: ")+"\n")
            f.write(str(int(input("ID: ")))+"\n")
            f.write(str(float(input("GPA: ")))+"\n")
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: You entered a String for ID or GPA.")
            f.seek(filepos)
            f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to save the inputs in variables first, and then save to file.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    
    f = open("StudentRecords.txt", "a")
    try:
        name = input("Name: ")+"\n"
        ID = str(int(input("ID: ")))+"\n"
        GPA = str(float(input("GPA: ")))+"\n"
        f.write(name + ID + GPA)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: You entered a String for ID or GPA.")
    
    f.close()
```

That being said, I would suggest updating the code a little more:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    name = input("Name: ") + "\n"
    try:
        ID = str(int(input("ID: "))) + "\n"
        GPA = str(float(input("GPA: "))) + "\n"

        with open("StudentRecords.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(name + ID + GPA)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: You entered a String for ID or GPA.")
```

Using `with` means you won't have to deal with the `f.close()`, among other things, and so you won't forget it. And since the `name = ...` line doesn't seem to need a try-except block, we can move it outside.

Comment: The second example writes the data whether it's valid or not. (Or tries to, anyway. Some of the variables won't be set.)

Comment: @kindall You are of course correct. Thanks! I've updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown you a way to validate your data, but right now the program just stops if the user makes a mistake. You really want some way for them to correct their error and continue.

To put this in your main routine would require a separate loop and `try`/`except` structure for each number, which isn't too bad right now with two values, but gets unwieldy as you add more.

So instead of repeating ourselves, let's write a function that repeats until the user enters a valid number.  We can pass in the type of number we want (`int` or `float`).

```
def inputnum(prompt, T=float):
    while True:
        try:
            return T(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(">>> You entered an nvalid number. Please try again.")
```

Then call that function to get your numbers (combined with some other small improvements):

```
with open("StudentRecords.txt", "a") as f:
    for i in range(5):
        name = input("Name: ")
        ID = inputnum("ID: ", int)
        GPA = inputnum("GPA: ", float)
        f.write(f"{name}\n{ID}\n{GPA}\n")
```